# Ripple effect on button in dialog is not smooth

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, rippledrawable

I create my `Dialog` like this:

The layout `dialog_app_rating`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_large"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <TextView
        fontPath="@string/font_roboto_bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:text="@string/rating_remind_title"
        android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_large"
        tools:text="Rate my app" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:text="@string/rating_remind_msg"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
        tools:text="Rate if it is useful" />

    <com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
        android:id="@+id/app_rating_rb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        app:srb_borderColor="@color/grey"
        app:srb_fillColor="@color/pink"
        app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
        app:srb_rating="5"
        app:srb_starBorderWidth="1"
        app:srb_starSize="@dimen/spacing_larger"
        app:srb_starsSeparation="@dimen/spacing_small"
        app:srb_stepSize="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/not_show_again_btn"
            style="?attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/text_button_height"
            android:text="@string/rating_remind_dont_show_again"
            android:textColor="@color/text_blue" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/send_btn"
            style="?attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/text_button_height"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textColor="@color/text_blue" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code for `RatingDialog`:

```
class RatingDialog extends Dialog {
    @BindView(R.id.app_rating_rb) SimpleRatingBar mAppRatingBar;
    @BindView(R.id.not_show_again_btn) View mNotAgainBtn;
    @BindView(R.id.send_btn) View mSendBtn;

    RatingDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.DialogTheme);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_app_rating);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, this);

        mNotAgainBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSendBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    // Other implementation...
}
```

My `DialogTheme` in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnchanged|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

It simply has some text, a rating bar, and 2 buttons. The buttons have **Ripple effect** on touch by default.

The problem is the Ripple effect not smooth when using in `Dialog`. It dims the background, shows a ripple and delays a bit then finish like the frame is being skipped. I've tried the effect on other dialogs as well but the problem is the same. Is that Android set low-priority for animation for `Dialog` only or something wrong with my config, can I fix it?

Thanks in advance